# Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_database' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys I'm trying to use 'firebase_database' but on run I'm getting this error `Could not get unknown property 'android' for the project ':firebase_database' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`
For all the dependencies I've imported the latest versions so I don't understand why. Running flutter doctor everything checks out well. Here is the whole error message.
what went wrong: a problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_database'.
 > could not load compiled classes for build file 'c:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-6.0.0\android\build.gradle' from cache. 
 > failed to notify project evaluation listener.
 > could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_database' of type org.gradle.api.project.
 > could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.defaultdependencyhandler.
Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: jitney_cabs
description: The best Taxi App in town.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0 
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.8 
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.1 


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - images/car_android.png
     - images/car_ios.png
     - images/desticon.png
     - images/desticon1.png
     - images/logo.png
     - images/logo1.png
     - images/logo2.png
     - images/logo3.png
     - images/pickicon.png
     - images/posimarker.png
     - images/redmarker.png
     - images/taxi.png
     - images/user_icon.png

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Signatra.ttf
    - family: Brand-Regular
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/bolt-regular.ttf
    - family: Brand Bold
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/bolt-semigold.ttf    
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```